# ASP.NET Javascript is not being send to jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nicedit

I develop in ASP.NET MVC3, I have the code below to send the view which contains some javascript , and it will be loaded in a jQuery UI dialog on client side, but I don't see the Javascript code anywhere in the client side,

View :

```
@model APS.HelpDesk.Data.App_TaskComment
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AllAddComment", new { area = "Task" }, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "AddCommnetloadingGif",
    UpdateTargetId = "AllCommentList" + Model.TaskId,
    OnSuccess = " $('#AddCommentDialog').dialog('close');"
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskId)
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.TaskId" id="TaskId" />
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("کامنت جديد")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <textarea id="CommentText" rows="2" name="CommentText" data-val-required="نوشتن کامنت ضروری است"
            data-val="true" cols="20"></textarea>
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentText)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="ارسال" />
    </p>
    <div id="AddCommnetloadingGif" style="display: none">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader/1.gif")" />
    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
            new nicEditor({ iconsPath: '@Url.Content("~/Content/WYSIWYG/nicEditorIcons.gif")' }).panelInstance('CommentText');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Dialog's code fromFirebug

```
<div style="outline: 0px; height: auto; width: 500px; position: absolute; top: 385px; left: 379px; display: block; z-index: 1002; " class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-AddCommentDialog"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-AddCommentDialog">ايجاد کامنت جديد</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div id="AddCommentDialog" style="text-align: right; width: auto; min-height: 108px; height: auto; " class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">

<form action="/Task/Task/AllAddComment" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#AddCommnetloadingGif" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success=" $('#AddCommentDialog').dialog('close');" data-ajax-update="#AllCommentList15" id="form0" method="post"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TaskId must be a number." data-val-required="The TaskId field is required." id="TaskId" name="TaskId" type="hidden" value="15">    <input type="hidden" value="15" id="TaskId">
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="">کامنت جديد</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <textarea id="CommentText" rows="2" name="CommentText" data-val-required="نوشتن کامنت ضروری است" data-val="true" cols="20"></textarea>
        <br>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CommentText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="ارسال">
    </p>
    <div id="AddCommnetloadingGif" style="display: none">
        <img src="/Content/Images/ajax-loader/1.gif">
    </div>
</form>
</div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style=""></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style=""></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style=""></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style=""></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; "></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1002; "></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1003; "></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1004; "></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, I can see it and also the script works (put an `alert`):

[image]

And here's my test code (simplified of course to remove all the noise):

Model:

```
public class App_TaskComment
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Dialog()
    {
        var model = new App_TaskComment();
        return PartialView("_dialog", model);
    }
}
```

Main view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("dialog")';
        $('<div id="dialog">Loading...</div>').appendTo('body').dialog({
            modal: true
        }).load(url, { });
    });
</script>

<div id="AddCommentDialog"></div>
```

Dialog partial loaded with AJAX (`~/Views/Home/_Dialog.cshtml`):

```
@model App_TaskComment
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AllAddComment", new { area = "Task" }, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "AddCommnetloadingGif",
    UpdateTargetId = "AllCommentList" + Model.TaskId,
    OnSuccess = "$('#AddCommentDialog').dialog('close');"
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskId)
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.TaskId" id="TaskId" />
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("کامنت جديد")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <textarea id="CommentText" rows="2" name="CommentText" data-val-required="نوشتن کامنت ضروری است"
            data-val="true" cols="20"></textarea>
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CommentText)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="ارسال" />
    </p>
    <div id="AddCommnetloadingGif" style="display: none">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader/1.gif")" />
    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
            new nicEditor({ iconsPath: '@Url.Content("~/Content/WYSIWYG/nicEditorIcons.gif")' }).panelInstance('CommentText');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: alert is being triggered but I can't see the alert in firebug.

Comment: Where are you looking in FireBug? Did you look at the Console tab as shown in my screenshot? It is where you see the AJAX request. Then simply expand it and analyze the response returned by the server. You will see the script. The browser simply interprets inline scripts directly when added with AJAX. It doesn't actually add them to the DOM so if you are exploring your DOM with FireBug you won't see them.